# How to return OkObjectResult and BadObjectResult - C# Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, http

I am getting the following error "Can not implicitly convert type "Microsoft.AspNetCore.OkObjectResult" to "Microsoft.Omex.Bulk.Accessibility.Logging.AccessibilityErrorOutput"when I try to execute the following line:

Microsoft.Omex.Bulk.Accessibility.Logging.AccessibilityErrorOutput, is another class in the project. But it is not being used in this class, so what am I doing wrong here?

I want to return HTTP results when the function is successful or not successfully executed.

```
        filePath ?? return new OkObjectResult("Accessibility Checker function executed successfully") : return new BadRequestObjectResult("Function did not execute successfully");
```

The full code of the Azure Function API:

```
namespace Microsoft.Omex.Bulk.Accessibility.Checker;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Attributes;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Omex.Bulk.Accessibility.Logging;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

/// <summmary>
/// Azure function class to manage functional processing of Word document, Excel spreadsheet,
/// Powerpoint presentation to detect acccessibility issues.
/// </summary>
public class AccCheckerForOpenXML
{
    private readonly ILogger<AccCheckerForOpenXML> logger;
    public AccCheckerForOpenXML(ILogger<AccCheckerForOpenXML> log) => this.logger = log;
    /// <summary>
    /// Function that receives a httptrigger and then starts processing documents the Office Open XML files.
    /// </summary>
    
    [FunctionName("AccCheckerForOpenXML")]
    [OpenApiOperation(operationId: "Run", tags: new[] { "docName" })]
    [OpenApiParameter(name: "name", In = ParameterLocation.Query, Required = true, Type = typeof(string), Description = "The **Name** parameter")]
    [OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "text/plain", bodyType: typeof(string), Description = "The OK response")]
    public async Task<AccessibilityErrorOutput> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
    {
        this.logger.LogInformation("AccCheckerForDocx: Run method:HTTP trigger --  function processed a request."); // 
        string filePath = req.Query["name"]; // In the query will be a name
        var requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody); // If not the name will be in JSON
        filePath ??= data?.name;
        filePath ?? return new OkObjectResult("Accessibility Checker function executed successfully") : return new BadRequestObjectResult("Function did not execute successfully");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because your Task defines an `AccessibilityErrorOutput` return type here:

```cs
public async Task<AccessibilityErrorOutput> Run(...)] HttpRequest req)
```

If you want to use the `OkObjectResult` or the other results, you must specify your function to return a Task as follows:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(...)] HttpRequest req)
```